# Proving existence of inverses in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $E=\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\,x>1\}$ and consider the binary operation on E given by $x∗y:=x^{\ln y}$. Prove E is a group.

I have found the identity, shown it is associative and shown it is closed under *. I'm stuck on showing all the elements are invertible. I have that $x*x'=x'*x=e$ where $e=2.718\ldots$ is the identity. So $x^{\ln(x')}=(x')^{\ln( x)}=e$. but I'm stuck here, I don't know how to actually show this, can I just isolate $x'$ and then that's the units?

Comment: Note that you are looking to show that a certain equation has at least one solution (it will then be unique and all that automatically). A nice thing here is that you are working in the reals, so you can use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You should - of course - explain what $l$ and $n(y)$ are. EDIT: Ah, I see. It should be $x\ln(y)$, right?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp $x^{ln(y)}$ sorry!

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681950/how-to-prove-e-is-a-group), it is the same.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm a little confused by how to use IVT here, I've never used it outside of calc class...

Comment: Well, you fix $x$ and you want to find an $x'$ solving the equation. So find a $y$ making the expression smaller than $e$ and one making it bigger than $e$ and you can apply it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the link goes nowhere.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli The link is still correct, but the question was deleted afterwards (which was the idea), but can be still seen by users with high reputation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ah, ok.

Answer (score 2):

Well suppose you have $$x^{\ln x'}=e$$
Then, $$(\ln x')(\ln x) =\ln(x^{\ln x'})=\ln e=1$$
So, you must have $x'=e^{1/\ln x}$. Now check that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x * y = \exp( \log x \log y),$ and $\log$ is monotonic on reals bigger than one, the question reduces to showing that the set of positive reals is a group under multiplication.